# How to return more than one results in my foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RestSharp;

namespace Words
{
    public partial class FormWords : Form
    {
        private RestClient client;
        RestRequest request;

        public FormWords()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public double lng { get; set; }
            public double lat { get; set; }
        }

        private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080");
            request = new RestRequest("/searchaddr");

            request.AddParameter("addr", textBoxSearch.Text);

            IRestResponse<RootObject> searchResponse = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);

            comboBoxSearch.Show();
            comboBoxSearch.Items.Clear();

            **foreach (var results in searchResponse.Data.lat && searchResponse.Data.lng)**
            {
                comboBoxSearch.Items.Add(results.suggestion.ToString());
                comboBoxSearch.DroppedDown = true;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time out to read this.
I am trying to return more than one expected result within my API:

I know that's not how you do it, but is there any suggestions that someone can give for me to potentially return the lat and lng in my results?

Comment: i no not understand that much what you are trying to accomplish. But what about nested foreach?. Have you tried it?

Comment: Are you sure about the `&&` syntax?

Comment: Here is a bit more context, so I am making a call to an API, which outputs JSON. Within the results a lat and lng are returned per result. I just can't find a way to handle these results, I can handle a single one.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg that is the error I'm getting, I can't handle the lat AND lng in one result..

Comment: So what is the expected result / behavior? You want the combine the 2 lists into 1? If so then you can just do loop twice, once on the lat and another on the lng.

Comment: Your foreach should just be` foreach(var results in searchResponse)` then on the following line. I cant see an object in results called suggestion, you might want to place a breakpoint here and look at what's in results.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after? Appending the results from both lat and lng into the combobox items?

```
comboBoxSearch.DroppedDown = true;
foreach (var result in searchResponse.Data.lat)
{
    comboBoxSearch.Items.Add(result.suggestion.ToString());
}
foreach (var result in searchResponse.Data.lng)
{
    comboBoxSearch.Items.Add(result.suggestion.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `searchResponse.Data.lat && searchResponse.Data.lng` is not correct in C#. You might mean one of two things, both of them can be handled with LINQ:

**Enumerate through one list and then through the next**

Use `Enumerable.Concat`:

```
searchResponse.Data.lat.Concat(searchResponse.Data.lng)
```

**Enumerate in parallel through two lists**

Use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
searchResponse.Data.lat.Zip(searchResponse.Data.lng, (lat, lng) => new { lat, lng })
```

Answer (score 0):

So I made an mistake by not utilising the ToString() function:

```
var result = searchResponse.Data.lat.ToString();
            {
                textBoxLat.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            var result1 = searchResponse.Data.lng.ToString();
            {
                textBoxLng.Text = result1.ToString();
```